# How to get Windows XP/2003 information(Edition, SP number, etc.) from the registry?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Does anyone knows how to get information about the system from the registry?

I have machine, but I do not know what is the version, edition, sp version of OS.

I need to get this from registry in C#. I need to know it only for Win XP and Win 2003

Thanks in advance,
Vasyl

Comment: Actually the main problem for now is that I can't find Edition in the registry. I found that info is stored in "system32\prodspec.ini" file, is it correct to get it from there?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) class

OS version is:

```
Environment.OSVersion
```

Comment: Is it possible to use this for remote machine?

Comment: No this gets the local machine's environment

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you are looking for:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I get the Edition of OS?